# How to set a Character array as text for TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, character-arrays

```
    userString=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.letter);
    checkButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
    checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
public void onClick(View v){
    char answer[]=null;int i;
    String userEntry=userString.getText().toString();
    for(i=0;i<userEntry.length();i++)
    {
    answer[i]='_';
    }
    text.setText(answer, 0, i);
    }
    }});
```

When I run the above code it says"The Application has stopped unexpectedly.Please Try again".How do i solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to place items (characters) into an array that has not been allocated. you need something like

```
char answer[] = new char[size];
```

at some point prior to placing characters into it.

Comment: that will get you past the NullPointerException that you *must* be getting.

Comment: looks like your `for` loop tells us. use `userEntry.length()`, and i think you will be safe. `char answer[] = new char[userEntry.length()];`